# Apache Camel: pollEnrich does not call dynamic URI

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route to poll the email from the server. In the `FunctionRoute` I am trying to pass the subject of the email I want to fetch by the IMAP protocol using pollEnrich method in the `EmailPollingRoute`. Currently I am facing problem to make a dynamic URI endpoint. I noticed the headers are being cleared before calling the pollEnrich method. Therefore I tried to use the `${exchangeProperty.subject}` but there is no email is fetched. When I set the subject directly in the endpoint as String then the email is being fetched.

How can I set the subject dynamically in the pollEnrich method? The subject is being passed from the `FunctionRoute` to `EmailPollingRoute` route.

I appreciate any help

```
@Component
public class FunctionRoute extends EmailPollingRoute {
    
    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FunctionRoute.class);
    
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:process_polling_email_function")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                subject = "ABCD - Test1";
                exchange.setProperty("ABCD - Test1");
                LOGGER.info("1. subject - " + subject);
                
            }})                          
        //.setProperty("subject", constant("ABCD - Test1"))
        //.setHeader("subject", simple("ABCD - Test1"))
        .to("direct:process_polling_email");
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class EmailPollingRoute extends BaseRouteBuilder {
    
    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailPollingRoute.class);
        
    public String subject;
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
            
        //super.configure();
        //2362
    
        //@formatter:off
        from("direct:process_polling_email")
            .routeId("routeId_EmailPollingRoute")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                
                     subject = exchange.getProperty("subject", String.class);
                     LOGGER.info("0001 - subjectB: (" + subject + ")");
                    
                }})
            
            .pollEnrich("imaps://XXXXXXX.info"
                    + "?username=XXXXX&"
                    + "password=XXXXXXX&"
                    +"folderName=Inbox/Test&"
                    +"searchTerm.fromSentDate=now-72h&"
                        +"searchTerm.subject=${exchangeProperty.subject}&"
                        +"fetchSize=1");
                    
            .to("log:newmail");
            
            //@formatter:on
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set pollEnrich URI dynamically using simple method, you can also specify timeout in similar way.

```java
.pollEnrich()
    .simple("imaps://XXXXXXX.info"
        + "?username=XXXXX&"
        + "password=XXXXXXX&"
        +"folderName=Inbox/Test&"
        +"searchTerm.fromSentDate=now-72h&"
        +"searchTerm.subject=${exchangeProperty.subject}&"
        +"fetchSize=1")
    .timeout(1000);
```